# resize image only if too big

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set image max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844433/set-image-max-size)

I have an area of `100x150 px` to display an image.

If the image to display is **larger** than this area, it should be resized (constraining width and height) to fit in the area, however when it is **smaller** than the area, it should remain in the original size.

Is this possible to do in `HTML`? or do I need to resize the image in serverside?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just specify the `max-width` and `max-height` styles:

```
img {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to accept the answer if this was of use to you.